# как посчитать кол-во целых точек лежащие на прямой

Tags: c++

Мне нужно найти кол-во точек, которые лежат внутри треугольника ABC с координатами (x,y).

Эту задачу можно решить через формулу Пика, но я столкнулся с проблемой. Я не знаю, как посчитать кол-во целых точек, которые лежат на прямых.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать( найти кол-во целых точек, которые лежат на прямых, а не внутри треугольника )

Answer (score 0):

Если абсолютные значения разностей целочисленных координат концов отрезка равны `dx` и `dy`, то на отрезке лежит `GCD(dx, dy) + 1` целочисленных точек, включая концы. (GCD - НОД, наибольший общий делитель).

Для замкнутого многоугольника, чтобы не учитывать вершины дважды, единицу можно убрать.

Comment: а, ну, точно. кол-во точек на отрезке = его расстоянию

Comment: Какому расстоянию?  Сколько точек будет на отрезке (0,0) - (6,8)?

Comment: Объясните ему про НОД более подробно, а то не поймет.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Ну я же расшифровал, да и НОД в школе изучают.